# Why does reloadData reset the height of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, reloaddata

to make my problem understandable, here an excerpt from my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

    taskTable.frame = CGRectMake(
        taskTable.frame.origin.x,
        taskTable.frame.origin.y,
        taskTable.frame.size.width,
        127
    );

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [self.taskTable reloadData];

}];
```

This is the basic situation: taskTable is a UITableView and it is integrated in a UIViewController. The first block works properly, the taskTable is after 0.5 seconds less on the height.

My problem starts in the completion block: after the taskTable is reloaded, the taskTable is again equal to the original height. The original height is set in the storyboard by the way.

Can someone tell me the reason for that? Can I prevent this behavior?

Here is a snapshot of the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it happens when `reloadData` is called? Or something else happens later? Maybe the table is autoresized by its parent?

Comment: Try the following: remove the reloadData from the complete, and then see if something happen. if nothing happen, try to search where you set the height in the code

Comment: If I comment out reloadData, everything works fine. I have already commented out everything possible, but after I run reloadData the height is set to the original height. I'll add snapshot from storyboard, maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Try disable the autoresize from your xib file.

Comment: okay, than it works (in my case I disabled autolayout) Is there a solution with autolayouting or is it a bug?

Comment: No, I don't think it is a bug. The autolayout is the new stuff since iOS 6. For me, it is the strategy of the layout, should use it in the right situation. Here is a good tutorial of it [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) and this is the help from Apple [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the question an answer:

you can disable autolayout to solve the problem, but that's not the nicest way.

How I solve the problem: I definied a constraint between the top of the superview and the tableView. After that I add the follwing in code (taskTableTop is that constraint):

```
[self.view removeConstraint:taskTableTop]; 

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:taskTable
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:jobDesc
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:0
                                                       constant:size.height + 38]];
```

I don't know if there is a easier way to do this.

If someone has a better answer ready, feel free to tell me (us) ;o)